# Getting Data from a VarArray using Delphi

Tags: arrays, web-services, delphi, variant

I have a WebService that returns a Variant me that it has an Array ie varArray, would like to know how to get the data that varArray.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

To get the content of a varArray you must use the [`VarArrayLowBound`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Variants.VarArrayLowBound) and [`VarArrayHighBound`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Variants.VarArrayHighBound) functions, then using a loop you can iterate over the array to get the data.

Try this sample

```
var
 i : integer;
 s : string; 
begin
  for i := VarArrayLowBound(vArray, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(vArray, 1) do
    s:=vArray[i];//copy the the content of the array i element into a string
```

Comment: I tried to give a ShowMessage in the variable "s" and it returns a blank value

Comment: What is the type of the data (string, integer, float) of the array ?

Comment: I managed to solve it was an error in the WebService, I sent an email asking to arrumarem ...

thank you

Comment: `VarArrayAsPSafeArray` allows direct access to the array and means you can avoid element-wise copying which gets very slow

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the underlying data type is `Byte`, and that the array is 1-dimensional, the way I would solve this is as follows:

```
function GetBytesFromVariant(const V: Variant): TBytes;
var
  Len: Integer;
  SafeArray: PVarArray;
begin
  Len := 1+VarArrayHighBound(vArray, 1)-VarArrayLowBound(vArray, 1);
  SetLength(Result, Len);
  SafeArray := VarArrayAsPSafeArray(V);
  Move(SafeArray.Data^, Pointer(Result)^, Length(a)*SizeOf(a[0]));
end;
```

If the underlying element type is something else, e.g. `Word`, `Integer` etc., it should be obvious how to modify this to match.